# Stop jquery from executing methods on div

Tags: jquery

I have a div "myDiv" & event that is bonded to it.

```
$('#myDiv').fadeOut(1000,function() {
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
```

Question is: how can i stop executing animation(if in process) & prevent from removing div?

Comment: Why do you need to stop it if you're the one attaching it in the first place ?

Comment: Under what circumstances do you want to stop executing the animation and prevent from removing the div?  There are a multitude of ways to go about doing this, including both stop() and using simple if...else statements.  Can you elaborate a little more please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep a ref to :

```
var a=$('#myDiv').fadeOut(1000,function() {
        $(this).remove(); 
    });
```

then , later -

```
a.stop( true, false);
```

the second param - you want it `false` :(although it's default)

```
A Boolean indicating whether to complete the current animation immediately.( you dont't want to complete)
```

See this example :

```
var a=$('body').fadeOut(4000,function() {
       alert('');
    });

setTimeout(function (){a.stop(true);},1000)
```

you won't see any alert...
http://jsbin.com/EMEsUKUM/2/edit